# Add csv import data to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, import

Good morning,
I created a script in php to import a csv file into the mysql table and so far no problem.

I added a column to the database not present in the csv file that I would like to populate based on the value of another column in the database.

For example, in my csv file and also in the database I have the vehicle type column (car, motorcycle, boat) and in the database I added the vehicle_id column that I would like to populate based on the value (car = 1, motorcycle = 2, boat = 3).

Is it possible to add such a step to the import script?

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: yea, in the middle of your csv import into the database, do your step; `if($vehicle_type == car) $vehicle_id = 1;` then just set the `$vehicle_id` as a parameter in your query and boom. Maybe including some code of an attempt could help narrow down to the solution

Comment: It doesn't make sense to load via PHP - load immediately into the table using LOAD DATA statement with input preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

In your import script before your insert query. create if statement

```
if($vehicle_type == "car"){
    $vehicle_id = 1;
}elseif($vehicle_type == "motorcycle"){
    $vehicle_id = 2;
}elseif($vehicle_type == "boat"){
    $vehicle_id = 3;
}
```